# Trying to print numbers in Jquery but rather than integers, I recieve [Object object]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am attempting to create a Calender using Jquery. But I don't understand how to have my object print the value it contains. I tried JSON.toString() on my table data but it did not correct my issue. Maybe I am misplacing the toString method in my code?

Before toString:

```
// get the number of days in the month
let daysInMonth = new Date(this.displayDate.getFullYear(), this.displayDate.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();

// get array of days to display
let days = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
  days.push(new Date(displayDate.getFullYear(), displayDate.getMonth(),i));
}

 console.log(this.monthNames[this.displayDate.getMonth()] + " " + this.displayDate.getFullYear());

td = $("<td>").attr("class", "day").text(days[i].getDate());
td.append(td);
```

Based on this [Firefox Javascript guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/object-object-in-javascript-meaning-in-js/) [object, object] is corrected using the JSON.toString() method. But when I implemented it

```
      td = $("<td>").attr("class", "day").text(days[i].getDate());
      td.append(JSON.stringify("td"));
```

[JSFiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ogqsc05f/1/#run)

Comment: *[object, object] is corrected using the JSON.toString()* - no, it's corrected by using the correct variable or property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add wrong variable to method .text().

In this code: you must add `days[i].getDate()` not `elem`

change `td= $("<th>").text(elem);` => `td= $("<th>").text(days[i].getDate());`

```
let monthDay = $('<monthDay>');
let textNode = $(days[i].getDate());
td = $("<td>");

td= $("<th>").text(days[i].getDate());  <--- like this
tr.append(td);
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 133 : `let textNode = $(days[i].getDate());`

`$(days[i].getDate());` is an object, `days[i].getDate();` is a int and you want this int.

Then you can use your `textNode`